# Dynamic file names with Excel INDEX() function

Tags: excel, vba, indexing

I'm doing some data crunching work in Excel. What I need to do is to fetch values from a Cell (Say D3) from sequentially numbered workbooks like 1.xlsx, 2.xlsx, 3.xlsx...so on.

I can't use INDIRECT() function as it would require all the target files to be opened (which is not possible in my case). So, I'm using the INDEX() function with the following values:

INDEX( [**1.xlsx**]Sheet1!D:D, 1,1 )

Now, I want the bold part of the formula to be dyamic based on the number on left column as shown in the image below:
[image]
Somebody please suggest solution to the problem at hand as I'm tired on googling :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Should do all you need: `Public Function evalu(str As String) As Variant: evalu = Evaluate(str): End Function`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps someone will prove me wrong, but I don't believe it is possible to generate such dynamic referencing without resource to INDIRECT, unless you are happy with a longhand (and static) method such as:

`=INDEX(CHOOSE(ROWS($1:1),[1.xlsx]Sheet1!D:D,[2.xlsx]Sheet1!D:D,[3.xlsx]Sheet1!D:D),1,1)`

though this requires that each workbook reference be entered explicitly within the formula. As such, this also means that these cannot be created via reference to any cells within the worksheet, as you might have hoped.

Or, if VBA is an option:

```
Sub Indexing()

Dim i As Long

For i = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("B" & i).Formula = "=INDEX([" & Range("A" & i).Value & ".xlsx]Sheet1!D:D,1,1)"
Next i

End Sub
```

Regards

Comment: Isn't there any method for doing so via VBA?

Comment: You did not tag "VBA" in your post. Only "excel" and "indexing".

Comment: @Vijay Should be the accepted and upvoted answer then.